# Criar função que calcula fração irredutível Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, funções

estou desenvolvendo um desafio em Java, e preciso criar uma função que calcule uma fração irredutível para solucionar o problema.

**Criei uma função a partir de algumas pesquisar mas a função não calcula corretamente o valor.**

**Alguém saberia indicar qual o problema da minha função?**

Segue abaixo código da função.

**Função Java**

```
public void irreductibleFraction(int numerador, int denominador) 
    {
        int cont = 1;
        while ((numerador % cont == 0) && (denominador % cont == 0)) 
        {
            if(denominador != 0)
            {
                numerador /= cont;
                denominador /= cont;
                cont++;   
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

        }

        System.out.println(numerador + "/" + denominador);
}
```

Comment: Qual seria o valor esperado? Dê um exemplo pf.

Comment: Matematicamente, o jeito mais fácil seria dividir ambos pelo MDC

Comment: 0/1 mas me retorna 1/0. Com os números que estou testando, que foram disponibilizados pelo desafio.

Answer (score 1):

Eu usei recursividade para tornar o código um pouco mais legível

```
public static void reduzirFracao(int numerador,int denominador){
      
       int menor_numero = numerador < denominador ? numerador : denominador;
       
       for (int i = 2; i <= menor_numero; i++) {
           if(numerador % i == 0 && denominador % i == 0){
               reduzirFracao(numerador /i , denominador/i);
               return;
           }
       }

       System.out.println(numerador+"/"+denominador);

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Um dos problemas é que quando você realiza uma divisão inteira com sucesso (resto zero), você não tenta novamente o mesmo valor. Por exemplo, para 8/4 seu programa responde 4/2 porque ocorre a divisão por 2 apenas uma vez.

Outro problema é sua condição de parada. Ela para o loop quando ocorrem duas divisões com sucesso seguidas, o que não necessariamente encerra o processo.

Fiz uma versão da função abaixo.

```
public void irreductibleFraction(int numerador, int denominador) 
{
    int cont = 2;
    while (cont <= numerador && cont <= denominador) 
    {
        if(numerador % cont == 0 && denominador % cont ==0)
        {
            numerador /= cont;
            denominador /= cont;
        }
        else
        {
            cont++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(numerador + "/" + denominador);
}
```

Comment: Continua dando o mesmo resultado errado.

Comment: Para quais valores está dando errado?